# having trouble getting sales for quarter

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to pull out the sales totals for quarter 1. I can't seem to get this to work. Any suggestions?

```
$total = 0;
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales_order/collection')
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
   ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
      'from' => '2012-01-01',
      'to' => '2012-03-31'));
foreach ($orders as $order) {
   $total += $order->getGrandTotal();
}
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting the collection properly. There are multiple ways to do this, looks like you might've combined a couple methods:

1. `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()` or
2. `Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')`

However, if all you really want is to sum the single attribute `grand_total` it is **way** more efficient to build your own query rather that loading the entire sales order collection:

```
$db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$salesTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order');
list($total) = $db->fetchCol(
    $db->select()
       ->from($salesTable, array('grand_total' => 'SUM(grand_total)'))
       ->where('DATE(created_at) >= ?', '2012-01-01')
       ->where('DATE(created_at) <= ?', '2012-03-31')
);
echo $total;
```

Comment: @gandalf007: #2 would be slightly faster because it's saving you at least one function call, but IMHO creating your own query is the best way to achieve what you want (provided you don't need to do additional filtering like only adding status = 'complete' orders or something like that).